# NSThread and memory management

Tags: cocoa, nsthread

Imagine I create and execute an NSThread object using `detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:`. The method executed by the thread might look like this:

```
- (void)search {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // perform a lengthy search here.

    [pool release];
}
```

I then might use the `cancel` method to kill the thread while it's running, before the pool gets released. What happens to the NSAutoreleasePool object? I suppose it will leak, won't it?

Answer (score 2):

`-(void)cancel` doesn't force cancellation, it merely requests it. Your `-(void)search` will run to completion. Read "[Responding to the Cancel Command](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004591-RH2-SW18)" for details.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/Cocoa/managingconcurrency.html) for simple concurrent tasks.